# React Native | Error: Unable to resolve module in node_modules/react-native/index.js

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

Whenever I run my React native App with react-native run-ios I get the following error:

> Error: Unable to resolve module ./Libraries/Components/DatePicker/DatePickerIOS from /Users/antonhorl3/WebstormProjects/sagly/client/node_modules/react-native/index.js:

> None of these files exist:
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/DatePicker/DatePickerIOS(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/DatePicker/DatePickerIOS/index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
> 15 | import typeof ActivityIndicator from './Libraries/Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator';
> 16 | import typeof Button from './Libraries/Components/Button';
> 17 | import typeof DatePickerIOS from './Libraries/Components/DatePicker/DatePickerIOS';
> |                                   ^
> 18 | import typeof DrawerLayoutAndroid from './Libraries/Components/DrawerAndroid/DrawerLayoutAndroid';
> 19 | import typeof FlatList from './Libraries/Lists/FlatList';
> 20 | import typeof Image from './Libraries/Image/Image';
> at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/antonhorl3/WebstormProjects/sagly/client/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:107:15)
> at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/antonhorl3/WebstormProjects/sagly/client/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:288:43)
> at Object.resolve (/Users/antonhorl3/WebstormProjects/sagly/client/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:129:24)
> at resolve (/Users/antonhorl3/WebstormProjects/sagly/client/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
> at /Users/antonhorl3/WebstormProjects/sagly/client/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:412:26
> at Array.reduce ()
> at resolveDependencies (/Users/antonhorl3/WebstormProjects/sagly/client/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
> at processModule (/Users/antonhorl3/WebstormProjects/sagly/client/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
> at async addDependency (/Users/antonhorl3/WebstormProjects/sagly/client/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:230:18)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)`

I did not make any changes to my code, the issue just came up. I did update Xcode, that is only change I think I have made. I am very lost.

The import statement in the react-native module is correct, and the file do exist.

This is my environment:

```
 System:
    OS: macOS 13.2.1
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Memory: 40.24 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.13.2 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.1.2 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.4, iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 26, 29, 30, 31
      Build Tools: 19.1.0, 23.0.1, 23.0.3, 27.0.3, 29.0.2, 29.0.3, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 33.0.0
      System Images: android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 4.1 AI-201.8743.12.41.7199119
    Xcode: 14.3/14E222b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.17 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: 5.0.1-alpha.2 => 5.0.1-alpha.2 
    react: 18.0.0-rc.0 => 18.0.0-rc.0 
    react-native: 0.65.3 => 0.65.3 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

If you need more information I am happy to add or edit my question.

Thanks for the help.

What I have tried:

- Restarting my Laptop
- react-native start -- --reset-cache
- rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
- yarn start --reset-cache
- watchman watch-del-all
- deleting node_modules and reinstalling them

The app should run without this error.

This is my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "assets/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "0.2.7",
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "2.1.5",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^5.2.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.15.14",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "5.0.1-alpha.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "7.1.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.8.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "7.0.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.8.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "5.14.4",
    "i18next": "^21.8.14",
    "jwt-decode": "3.1.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "raygun4reactnative": "1.1.5",
    "react": "18.0.0-rc.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.18.1",
    "react-native": "0.65.3",
    "react-native-android-keyboard-adjust": "1.2.0",
    "react-native-codegen": "0.0.7",
    "react-native-eject": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.19.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.10.3",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^9.1.1",
    "react-native-iap": "^12.8.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.7.3",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-in-app-review": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-offline": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-purchases": "^5.13.0",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "1.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "3.6.0",
    "react-native-searchable-dropdown": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-share": "^7.3.6",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "3.9.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-triangle": "^0.0.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "8.1.0",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-webview": "11.6.4",
    "react-native-wheel-scroll-picker": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "2.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "2.10.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "tcomb-form-native": "0.6.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.13.10",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.23.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.65.2",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^4.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: try deleting podlock file and installing pods again

Comment: thanks for the comment but this does not help either

Comment: I added my package.json

Comment: I think this package does not exist. When I run your command I get this error: `404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/DatePickerIOS - Not found`

Comment: Allright, what package did you install recently? (That broke your code)

Comment: I am not sure if a package broke my code, but the two packages I installed the latest are: `"react-native-purchases": "^5.13.0"` and `"react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3"`

Comment: Can you try this `npm start -- --reset-cache` (terminate metro first)

Comment: This does not help either.

Comment: I downgraded Xcode and it works now again as expected. So I probably need to upgrade react native so that it works with the new Xcode version.

Comment: I have the same issue with the newest version of Xcode ughhh

Comment: Exact same issue here with Xcode version 14.3 which has been causing all sorts of other issues too!

Comment: @AntonHörl which Xcode version did you downgrade to?

Comment: They are patching releases to fix Xcode 14.3 issue, so you don't need to downgrade anymore. Confirmed it works with 0.70.8

Comment: I have my React native Expo app and today I tried to do Expo Start and saw same thing. Anything I should do? or I just ignore that for now?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a known issue with Xcode version 14.3. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36635.

Comment: So for now I just ignore the issues right? Because exactly I didn't change anything on the project and today tried to do Expo Start and saw the issues.

Comment: A couple days ago, I sent an iOS app for review, and they complained about getting a blank screen upon launch, today I got to know that this exact issue was the reason...

Comment: Same error on version 15 :(

Answer (score 3):

For those who have some strict deadlines, and can't wait for the fixes at the moment, simply downgrade your Xcode version from `14.3` to `14.2`, or any other version that you had installed previously.

In my case, downgrading from version `14.3` to `14.2` resolved my issue.

You can download older versions of Xcode from [here](https://xcodereleases.com).

Comment: I'm on Xcode 15 what am I supposed to do?? This stack is garbage. All I hear is downgrade this and dowgrade that (already pinned 3 packages). But then apple forces you to upgrade. Good job Facebook and Apple.

Comment: There are no issues with Xcode 15 at all. Instead everything runs smoothly on Xcode 15, the archives are done surpassingly quicker.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while using node module "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.10". I was able to resolve this by adding node module "@react-native-community/datetimepicker".

```
yarn add @react-native-community/datetimepicker
cd ios
pod install
```

Hope this helps!